# google chrome returns wrong window height?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

i have been working on this script http://www.acgunsdcroses.com/agencymeter/. it seems like only google chrome is returning a wrong window height and thus sets the height of the divs wrong, leaving a white space between the red and blue divs. strangely enough this only happens when you load the page for the first time in a new window/tab, upon reload it works fine.

can you guys reproduce this and do you have any idea what i could do about this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question about a Google Chrome bug, but this is my recommendation for your particular situation:

I would use `CSS` instead of setting the page up with JavaScript:

**EXAMPLE**

[Example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/iqabe)

**HTML**

```
<div id="received">27 Emails received since Wed, 06 Jan 2010 05:00:05</div>
<div id="sent">10 Emails sent since Wed, 06 Jan 2010 05:00:05</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0 }

#received, #sent { position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100%; }
#received { top: 0; bottom: 200px;  background-color: #ff0000; }
#sent     { bottom: 0; height: 200px; background-color: #0000ff; }
```

**UPDATE**

You could still play with the split ratio using JavaScript, but it would always fill the screen, even if the calculations are 2 or 3 pixels off from what you ideally wanted:

**JS**

```
var received = document.getElementById('received'),
    sent     = document.getElementById('sent');

// Be sure to set 'sent' height to whatever you set 'received' bottom to:
received.style.bottom = "300px";
sent.style.height     = "300px";

// You should also be able to use percentages:
received.style.bottom = "30%"; // Received will occupy 70%
sent.style.height     = "30%"; // Sent will occupy 30%
```

Comment: hey doug, 

interesting approach! my script adjusts the height of the two colored areas based on varying database input. they should cover the entire screen area but each represent the amount of emails sent or received. so now i wonder if the css based approach would still work for that?

thank you,
a.i

Comment: @a.i. Yes, you could do a small combination of both methods. I updated my answer to reflect that.